# getContext() returns null in Fragment. View seems to be unattached

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

`Glide.with((getContext())).load(user.getImgURl()).into(image_profile);`

The above line is returning getContext as null hence allowing the app to crash.
I have added this in a fragment under the onDataChange method as follows.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    image_profile=view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    username=view.findViewById(R.id.username);


    storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    fuser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());




    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            username.setText(user.getUsername());

            if(user.getImgURl()!= null && user.getImgURl().equals("default")){
                image_profile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }else{

            Glide.with((getContext())).load(user.getImgURl()).into(image_profile);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    image_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openImage();
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

The code is supposed to retrieve an image from firebase storage and display it onto the image_profile.

The following is the logcat for the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
```

### You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).

```
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:31)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:675)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:707)
        at com.hello.khushboo.messaging.Fragments.ProfileFragment$1.onDataChange(ProfileFragment.java:110)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in fragment use getActivity() for context like this :
 below code:

```
 Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(imageUri)
            .into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checked various stuffs on internet , finally this one worked.

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            username.setText(user.getUsername());
            if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                image_profile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                if(getContext()!=null)
               Glide.with(getActivity()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(image_profile);
            }
        }
```

To know more about life cycle of fragments please go through this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: The line ``` if(getContext()!=null)```fixed it for me. Nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check to null

```
if (getContext() != null) {
    Glide.with((getContext())).load(user.getImgURl()).into(image_profile);
}
```

And remove Firebase listener in onDestroyView() or onDestroy():

```
reference.removeEventListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you! The destroyer method allows the context to not be null. However I am still unable to view the image! Any take on that?

Answer (score 0):

```
If(isAdded()) {
   Glide.with((getActivity().getContext())).load(user.getImgURl()).into(image_profile)
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works.

```
 Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(user.getImgURl()).into(image_profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getContext`. Try using `getActivity`. Works all the time for me. Putting this in code, we have:

```
Glide.with((getActivity())).load(user.getImgURl()).into(image_profile);
```

### More details

This is the relationship between an Activity and a Context:

```
  ↳ android.content.Context
      ↳ android.content.ContextWrapper
          ↳ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
              ↳ android.app.Activity
```

From the illustration above, we can see that Activity is a type of Context and that's why it's usable here.

I hope this helps. Merry coding.